# Displaying a particular book info on click of a particular book image

Tags: image, jsp, servlets, onclick

I have Books.jsp page

This page retrieves bookname(bnm) from database and it calls a servlet named Books.java to retrieve image and display it.

```
<%@page import="javax.print.PrintService"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.sql.*,java.io.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>BooksInfo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="Next1.jsp" method="get">
        <%!Connection cn;
    Statement stm;
    ResultSet rs;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
    PreparedStatement psmt;%>

        <%!public void jspInit() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");         
            System.out.println("Connection created");

            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "hello");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }%>


        <% 
            stm = cn.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery("select bnm,image from bookdemo");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String s = rs.getString(1);
        %>
        <table><tr><td>
        <a href="Info.jsp"><img src ="Books"></img></a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <%
            out.write(s);
        %>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="book" value=<%=s%>>
        </td></tr></table>
        <%
            }
        %>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add & View Cart">
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Question:**
Now on click of a particular book I want to display that book's information on a separate Info.jsp.How do I do it?How do I get to know that a particular book image is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solution for this.

1. If your Book name and book image is in same table then you have a common id for both. In this case on click on book name another request will go to the servlet to fetch the image just like you did for Bookname.
2. If your bookname and image in different tables in database straight forward solution will be give the common name to book and image, so by the name you will be able to fetch the image from database.

There are multiple solutions for that. Another thing I don't recommend database connectivity in Jsp for best practice and security reasons.

Comment: How would I know that which book image is clicked??

Comment: Here I see that your book and image in the same table. You are fetching book name. Fetch the image as well. You will get the bytes. Convert the bytes into image.Here is the code Base64.encodeBase64String(image);

Comment: You need to include apache commons library for that.